# SQL Eliminate Duplicates with NO ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table with the following Columns...
Node, Date_Time, Market, Price

I would like to delete all but 1 record for each Node, Date time.

```
SELECT Node, Date_Time, MAX(Price) 
FROM Hourly_Data
Group BY Node, Date_Time
```

That gets the results I would like to see but cant figure out how to remove the other records.

Note - There is no ID for this table

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Answers will vary depending on database vendor.

Comment: Show your table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an easy sql-server method that creates a Row Number within a cte and deletes from it.  I believe this method also works for most RDBMS that support window functions and Common Table Expressions.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Node, Date_Time ORDER BY Price DESC)
    FROM
       Hourly_Data
)

DELETE
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum > 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that row numbering was exactly what I needed.  Just tested it on the test table and about to start it running on the full table

Comment: glad to help, in the future if you can tag your questions with the database server you are using e.g. sql-server, oracle, etc. you will get faster responses by more people. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps that are rather workaround than a simple one-command which will work in any relational database:

1. Create new table that looks just like the one you already have
2. Insert the data computed by your group-by query to newly created table
3. Drop the old table
4. Rename new table to the name the old one used to have

Just remember that locking takes place and you need to have some maintenance time to perform this action.

There are simpler ways to achieve this, but they are DBMS specific.